# Show a specific number of random objects from a selection and hide all others with js/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

What I did so far was the following:

```
function randomSelectObjects(randObjects, countShow){
    var i = 0;
    var countRandObjects = randObjects.length;
    var preselectedObj = false;
    randObjects.hide(); // hide all items
    while (i < countShow) { // while until we found enough items we can show
        preselectedObj = randObjects.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*countRandObjects)); // random select an object
        if(preselectedObj.is(':hidden')){ // make sure it is not already unhidden
            preselectedObj.show(); // show the object
            i++; // up the counter – done only in case it was not already visible
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var randObjects = $('.items');
randomSelectObjects(randObjects, 1);
```

The problem is that I will run into selecting an already revealed (`show()`) item inside `while` from time to time. I would love to remove that unnecessary overhead.

Unfortunately there seems to be no way to remove an object from a cached selection. `remove()` also removes the object from the DOM which is not (always) what I want.

Cloning the selection of objects first and then using `remove()` would work for the selection process but then there would be the overhead to match the selected items with the live DOM for actually `show()` them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is create a unique random array first. Hide all elements then loop through the array of random inidices and show matching elements

```
// wrap in simple jQuery plugin
$.fn.randomDisplay = function(max_items) {
  max_items = max_items || 5;
  //create array of unique random indices
  var randArr = randArray(this.length, max_items);
  // hide all then filter matches to show
  this.hide().filter(function(i){
     return randArr.indexOf(i) >-1
  }).show();

  // creates unique array
  function randArray(max, len) {
    var arr = [],   rand;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      rand = getRand(max)
      while (arr.indexOf(rand) > -1) {
        rand = getRand(max)
      }
      arr.push(rand);
    }
    return arr;
  }
  // random number helper
  function getRand(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max)
  }

}

// use
$(function(){
   $('.item').randomDisplay(7)
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/z4mmag58/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Switching my snippet with yours, I got pages calculation like forever before actually showing the content. I am investigating and let you know as soon as I figure it out. (The bug might be somewhere else...)